# Get the count of Associated tables using sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In my Case Account is a parent table  Account that has many Members, an Account has many Groups, Account has many Roles. So I tried getting a count of each table as follows.

```
  Account.findAll({
    subQuery: false, 

    where: {id: id},

    attributes: {
        include: ['*',
            [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("Members.id")), "usersCount"],
            [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("Groups.id")), "groupsCount"],
            [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("Roles.id")), "rolesCount"]]
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: Member, attributes: [], where: {accountId: id}
        },
        {
            model: Group, attributes: [], where: {accountId: id}
        },
        {
            model: Role, attributes: [], where: {accountId: id}
        }
    ],
    group: ['Account.id']
})
    .then(data => {
        let result = data.map(item => accountObj(item));
        return next(null, result[0]);
    })
    .catch(err => dbHelper.handleError(err, next));
```

It's giving me an incorrect count. Also tried various other options I found on stack overflow. But not found any solution for the above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to separate this query into three ones to count each child model record count separately OR remove `include` and `group` options and replace `Sequelize.fn` with `Sequelize.literal` with subqueries to count child records.

```js
Account.findAll({
    where: {id: id},
    attributes: {
        include: ['*',
  [Sequelize.literal("(SELECT COUNT(*) from members as m where m.account_id=account.id)", "usersCount"],
  [Sequelize.literal("(SELECT COUNT(*) from groups as g where g.account_id=account.id)", "groupsCount"],
  [Sequelize.literal("(SELECT COUNT(*) from roles as r where r.account_id=account.id)", "rolesCount"],
  ]
    }
})
```